# How to add pre-built javascript to react with webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, sanitization

I am trying to use [sanitize-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html) on my React/Webpack project.

The instructions for browser integration are:

- Clone repository
- Run npm install and build / minify.
- You'll find the minified and unminified versions of sanitize-html (with all its dependencies included) in the dist/ directory.

I did all of this and copied the files to the React/Webpack project and imported the file with:

```
const sanitizeHtml = require('../sanitize-html');
```

Everything work but I'm getting this message in the console:[image: error]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: perhaps try with `const sanitizeHtml = require('sanitize-html')` (without relative path)

Comment: AFAIK, this will work only if the library was installed using "npm install", this is a file "sanitize-html.js" that was copied to the project's directory

Answer (score 1):

If you have some precompiled libraries that you would normally include with a script tag in your html then you probably would not need to import it in react. Here is how you can use `jQuery` in react (I know jQuery in react is evil but is sometimes needed when using external libraries or in existing webpages).

jQuery creates a global variable, so you can use it with `window.$` or `window.jQuery`;

Comment: Great, I will add it as a script, but then it won't be part of the bundle, right?

Comment: right, it is an external script that you include directly in the html file. If you use `$`in react there will be an error, but `window.$` works